# htaccess file nomenclature creating problem in opening a popup window in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, .htaccess, popup

My htaccess file nomenclature creating problem in opening a window in IE

> **EDITED**

I have to open a colour picker which needs t be opened in popup, and I have

```
window.open('picker.html', null, "help=no,status=no,
scrollbars=no,resizable=no,toolbar=
no" + move + ",width=" + w + ",height=" + h + ",dependent=yes", true);
```

my base url goes like this:

http://www.mydoamin.com/

and the htaccess file has rewritten the above url from http://www.mydomain.com/30/

but when i wish to open the popup in IE the htaccess doesnt work for it and gives me url as http://www.mydomain.com/30/picker.html

and hence i get msg as broken link or NOT FOUND 
there is no such folder called "30" the path has to be like http://www.mydomain.com/picker.html

The rewrite rule of the particular page goes like this:

> RewriteRule
>   ^30/order-vinyl-banners.html
>   order_form.php?id=30 [NC]

why is it happening..
please help me to track it..

Comment: Please provide more information, like the contents of your .htaccess file and the full path of the file opening that pop-up.

Comment: How is it that the "htaccess" file is supposed to have anything to do with this problem? What happens if you (temporarily) just get rid of the file?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show `http://www.example.com/picker.html`, you need to tell the `open()` function so. Right now you're telling it "Open the URL `picker.html` relative to where I'm currently at", but you want "Open `picker.html` relative to the root". Try this instead:

```
window.open('/picker.html', null,
        "help=no,status=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,toolbar=no"
        + move + ",width=" + w + ",height=" + h + ",dependent=yes", true);
```

Comment: when i did this it gives me error as "/picker.html" not found

i has to deal with htaccess

Comment: @OM The Eternity - Then I assume `picker.html` is not where you think it is on your server. Are you sure that file exists?

Comment: Yes it exists and it works fine on my live server, this is creating problem in my test server  and in local wamp

Comment: @OM The Eternity - And on your test server the site isn't in a subdirectory or anything, right?

Comment: @OM The Eternity - Well, there must be something that's different between your test server and the live server. If you try typing the URL to `picker.html` in directly, it tells you it cannot be found?