# RewriteRule conflict

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following line on my .htaccess

```
LINE 1: RewriteRule ^user/account$ /bootstrap/user/account.php [NC]
LINE 2: RewriteRule ^user/account/picture$ /bootstrap/user/upload_picture.php [NC]
LINE 3: RewriteRule ^user/account/preferences$ /bootstrap/json/edit-preferences.php [NC]
LINE 4: RewriteRule ^user/account/password$ /bootstrap/json/change-password.php [NC]
```

LINE 1 works fine.
LINE 2 works fine.
LINE 3 error 404.
LINE 4 error 404.

Any idea?

---

BTW, on my local server, it works fine because it is placed on root directory. On my online server, it is placed on root directory in a folder bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to see maybe there's an extra / ending your online URLs?
You might want to add /? before the $ in your urls, and in the context of SEO you might redirect to one version from the other.

Also do not forget to check the urls that you rewrite to- it is possible that you are having trouble with the real URL, and then the rewriteRule is the wrong place to look at...

Also please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616690/htaccess-rules-differs-in-local-and-live-server)

**Edit**

I've checked your online url- and the "real" url doesn't work either. Like I said, the rewrite rules are the wrong place to look at in your situation.

Make sure that all the files and their dependencies are there, and that there's no internal dependency on your folder structure, which is physically different in your dev and production server.

Comment: nope, I am aware with /. Also you can check here live http://onebohol.com/user/account/preferences

Comment: @Mar Cejas Your physical url doesnt work either. Do you happen to have "require"s that rely on your physical structure of the local server, and the extra bootstrap folder could break?

Comment: Nevermind. I got the answer from my own. Thanks for your suggestions/answers/comments/efforts.

Comment: Well then you should post your answer for other people who might have problem in the future :-)